# Geocoding on the fly vs database lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geocoding

I'm starting a new rails project that integrates closely with Google Maps. When a user searches for a city, I'm trying to decide whether to geocode the address on the fly (using Google's Geocoding API) or to look up the city in a database pre-populated with lat/long. After I have the lat/long I will plot it on Google Maps.

Which do you think would perform better? With the database lookup, the table would have to be pretty large to account for all the cities I would need and I would have to fallback on the geocoding API anyway for any cities that I don't have in my database.

I wasn't sure if there is a common practice to this or not. I don't need a user's specific location, but just a city they are searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the table is no problem, as long as you index on the city name.

Performance of indexed database queries outspeed web API access by far.

An other point is, that you have better controll of the found data. For example, if you find more than one matching city, you can provide a choice of your DB entries, while Google sometimes reports none or some random (or at least unexpected) search result.

This is, why I had to change to a DB search first strategy in one of my project: Google somtimes didn't find my customers addresses but something total different (i.e. small villages with the same name as the expected bigger one)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do both?

Have the address's geocoded information in your database as "Address Cache" and then call the Google Maps Geocode API only if the address doesn't already exist in your database. That's the approach I used in my Google Maps to SugarCRM integration. It works well. BTW, the Google Maps Geocode API is impressively fast, so users rarely notice. Yet, there is a 2,500/day limit on request and it's also throttled to about 10 requests per second. So, considering those limits, I think a combination database/geocode approach is much better in the long run.

https://github.com/jjwdesign/JJWDesign-Google-Maps